# генерация base64 swift

Tags: java, swift, swift3, base64

есть пример генерации ключа на java

```
signature = Base64.encode(HMAC_SHA1.digest(data, Base64.decode(client_secret)))
```

Данные для генерации

```
data = "3tme3bnmepmibhvv1toq4xfed866faaa06aa1b13979653502956"
secret_key = "0gkp7n6tnwdn816kyzfp26s3e"
```

на выходе нужно получить

```
result = 1WVoLPXcqJVKaxSK50ArFHtKtnM=
```

пробовал реализовать вот так

```
extension Data {

    func hmacsha1(key: String) -> String? {
        guard let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: key) else {
            return nil
        }
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        self.withUnsafeBytes({ dataBytes in
            keyData.withUnsafeBytes({ keyDataBytes in
                CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), keyDataBytes, keyData.count, dataBytes, keyData.count, &digest)
            })
        })
        return Data(bytes: digest).base64EncodedString()
    }

}

let data = Data("Test".utf8)
let key = Data("Key".utf8).base64EncodedString()
let hmac = data.hmacsha1(key: key)

result = zWYYH5p8jUn6cAHjP+oB6IbOUuU=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прикрепил решение если кому нибудь когда нибудь пнадобится

```
extension String {
    func hmac(algorithm: kCCHmacAlgSHA1, key: NSData) -> String {
        let cKey = key
        let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
        var cHMAC = [CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH]
        CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cKey.bytes, cKey.length, cData, Int(strlen(cData!)), &cHMAC)
        let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: cHMAC, length: cHMAC)
        let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        return String(hmacBase64)
    }
}

let hmacResult: String = cData.hmac(algorithm: kCCHmacAlgSHA1, key: keyData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
extension String {
    func hmacSha1(with key: String) -> String {
        let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        let length : Int = Int(strlen(cKey!))
        let data : Int = Int(strlen(cData!))
        CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cKey!,length , cData!, data, &result)
        let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)))
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: hmacData.length)
        hmacData.getBytes(&bytes, length: hmacData.length)
        return Data(bytes).base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```